# Копирование/восстановление структуры таблиц из памяти phpstorm

Tags: mysql, phpstorm

Есть phpstorm. Через него велась работа с бд. По понятным причинам бд удалена и доступа туда более нету. Структура таблиц без данных осталась в phpstorm. Как можно восстановить эту бд (только таблицы) используя неизвестные мне возможности phpstorm и то что осталось? Можно долго переписывать ручками прожимая каждую колонку но это долго. Уже делал так)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: на БД правой мышью если кликнуть, потом SQL Scripts -> Generate DDL Scripts, то не работает без подключения? Или в Import/Export  есть restore какой-то

Comment: "понятные причины" что-то не особо понятны

Comment: @teran https://disk.yandex.ru/i/S424ja4ISuggBg . Забыл удалить пользователя root в бд. За эти 10 минут как я создал бд кто-то успел залезть всё удалить и выставить биткоин счет чтобы дать дамп этой бд)

Comment: так и что у вас там Generate DDL to clipboard генерит?

Comment: @teran Да все отлично. Все как надо. Боялся абы куда жать чтобы не потерять. Буду знать на будущее спасибо! Если требуется, добавьте в ответ. помечу как решение

Comment: оформил ответом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете сгенерировать DDL скрипты создания сущностей БД через контекстное меню БД в SQL Scripts -> Generate DDL Scripts. Наименование пунктов могут различаться в зависимости от версии шторма. Процедура не требует активного подключения к БД. Полученные скрипты выполнить на новом экземпляре сервера/БД.